# Access 2007 "Return without Gosub" after i deleted a button

Tags: ms-access-2007

SO something strange happened, I was cleaning up my database and deleted a button that honestly just closed the current form and opened a different datasheet. now whenever i try to select a field or do anything I get things like The LinkMasterFields property setting has produced this error: 'Return without GoSub' ...i Dont really understand how this could all of a sudden happen

thanks for any input it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved, Allthough i did delete the button the error was caused when i didnt delete the click event associated with the button. It is strange i think because i have most certainly deleted buttons before and didnt need to delete there click event scripts and everything still worked fine.